# Locate a dot with the same xpath in a highchart

Tags: xpath, highcharts

I have a highchart in a graphic with dots and I need to get the data inside every dot but I can't be able to achieve the different dots because they have all the same xpath!!!
I show you:

[one dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEWsC.jpg)

[other dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzZXV.jpg)

How could I locate the different dots if they all have the same xpath??

I have the following code, but if they have the same xpath, I can't locate different dots...

```
    **String x1 = ".//*[@id='highcharts-0']/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g'][5]/*[name()='g'][18]/*[name()='path'][8]"; 
    String x2 = ".//*[@id='highcharts-0']/div/span/span";    //xpath tooltip
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(x1));
    // action class para clickear el punto
    Actions action = new Actions((WebDriver) driver);
    action.click(element).build().perform();
    String toolTipText2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(x2)).getText();  
    if(!toolTipText2.contains(string))  sb.append("===> Content error: ");**
```

Thanks so much for your help!!!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "get the data inside every dot" (which data?)? And what do you mean by "locate"? Also: "dots" in this case are the `marker` for each `point` in the `series`.

Comment: The data (shown info) in the tooltip (I show it in the images). "Locate" is locate, identify the dot, the path to achieve that dot.

Comment: "data in the tooltip" is still not specific, and "locate" could still mean multiple things according to that definition. I have attempted to answer below based on the simplest interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

The data in the "dots" is just the chart data.

You can access it, and much more, by navigating via

```
chart.series[i].data[j]
```

Fiddle Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/u4cb2rk4/

Or by accessing the data source directly.